# How to change colors of multiple specific keywords

Tags: atom-editor, text-editor

I'm parameterizing Atom. I'd like to apply a rule that automatically changes the color of multiple keywords.

I found a way of doing that but only for one word. In the init.coffee file:

```
customHighlights = (editor) ->
  editor.scan /AND/, (result) ->
    options = {
      type: "text"
      class: "operator"
    }

    marker = editor.markBufferRange result.range
    decoration = editor.decorateMarker marker, options

atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) ->
  customHighlights(editor)

  editor.onDidStopChanging ->
    customHighlights(editor)
```

In the style.less file:

```
.operator {
  color: hsl(349, 66%, 56%);
}
```

I changed "AND" automatically in a given file.

How can I do this for several words? I'd like to apply the same design, as "AND", to "OR", and then apply a different design to the characters representing quotation marks (`""`).